# What is the point of using an initial estimate when sigma-clipping data?

Tags: outliers, robust, astronomy

I am reading a paper that is discussing sigma clipping some velocity data, lets call it a set $V$, and it says:

> The center at each iteration of the $3\sigma$ clipping is the biweight average, and $\sigma$ is calculated from the biweight variance... We do not make a hard velocity cut; the initial estimate of $\sigma$ used in the iterative clipping is determined from the [values] located within $4000\text{ km s}^{-1}$ of the center...

At first I thought that it simply meant to remove all datapoints $v_i$ in $V$ if $v_i > \beta + 4000$ or $v_i < \beta - 4000$ (where $\beta$ is the center - the biweight average).

However, they also say,

> We do not make a hard velocity cut.

So I'm not sure what to do. What does it mean to use an "initial estimate" in the context? Does it rather mean that I only calculate $\sigma$ with the datapoints inside this range within $4000\text{ km s}^{-1}$ , then clip? Though that seems that it would have the same effect as first removing data outside that range.

Comment: I don't quite see how this is neither the [tag:distributions] nor [tag:weighted-sampling] question. This seems like a particular technique to remove outliers, in which case it is best referred to [tag:outliers] or [tag:robust].